# fast way to modify multiple columns in dataframe with a numpy array Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe with mixed dtypes e.g. shape (1000, 200), now I'd like to assign/update 100 columns of this df with a numpy (integer) array shape (1000, 100).

Initially what I did is very basic, something like: `df.loc[:, [100 COLUMNS]] = my_np_array`, however I have a running time limit, the faster all my code executes the better. After doing line profiling on my code, it turns out almost 70% time my code spent was on this assignment operation, so then I went on to look for faster method, the only other method I came across is to modify the underlying array directly i.e. `df.values[:, [100 COLUMN INDICES] = my_np_array`. This was much much faster and I was pretty satisfied with it for a moment. (if any can shed some light on why its much faster would also appreciate)

Only until I discovered the values of my dataframe is actually not changed, it seems like if the dataframe has **mixed** dtypes then `.values` would return a copy instead of a view/reference, which means all the changes I made were not applied to the original values, so I can't just do modification on `.values`. Now I'm stuck, if anyone can think of ways to improve this assignment operation would be great.

(One potential method I'm thinking is to create a separate dataframe from this numpy array and then  do a merge with original df, however i actually need to do the assignment operation many times, so this probably doesn't work as the time of creating a dataframe and merge would also not be too small)

Comment: I'm surprised that `df.loc[:, [100 columns]] = my_np_array` is the bottleneck. You can also try `for i,col in enumerate([100 columns]): df[col] = my_np_array[:,i]`.

Comment: @QuangHoang interesting suggestion, will give it a try, given it runs under loop 100 times, wouldnt this be even slower?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but what about making the new values a dataframe and then using [df.assign()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) as another option?

Comment: @QuangHoang Was busy, now I just tried out for loop assigning, surprisingly it is x2 faster than setting the whole columns at once, not sure why. What I ended up doing is actually creating a new dataframe with same index from the np array and the concat onto df, it turns out to be x4 times faster than setting all at once (so x2 faster than for loop assigning) and it passed my code running time restriction.